# Using macruby, how do I set up a completion block for a Core Animation transaction?

Tags: macos, core-animation, osx-snow-leopard, macruby

I'm using MacRuby to do Core Animation programming. I've tried all I can think of and searched all over  (and maybe it can't be done in 'pure' macruby) but I can't figure out how to specify a block of MacRuby code as a completion block to be called when an animation transaction is finished.  I know there are other ways to do what I want but this seems to be the cleanest for me and the way things are moving in Cocoa.  Anyway, this is what I've got:

```
CATransaction.begin  # start the transaction
#
# ...set up animation (works fine!)
#
CATransaction.setCompletionBlock(...)          <---- Here's the problem
CATransaction.commit  # end the transaction
```

Without the 'setCompletionBlock' line the animation runs fine.  The parameter to this setter method is defined (in Objective-C) as:

```
void (^)(void))block
```

And is described as:

> "a block object called when animations for this transaction group are > completed. The block object takes no parameters and returns no value."

I've tried different things (but I'm just guessing at this point):

```
CATransaction.setCompletionBlock({ some code })

CATransaction.setCompletionBlock(Proc.new { some code })

CATransaction.setCompletionBlock(lambda { some code })

CATransaction.setCompletionBlock(method(:aMethod))
...
def aMethod
  ...
end
```

Am I way off?  Do I have to make an Objective-C wrapper of some sort to do it?  Or can't it be done?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after quite a roundabout trip searching through scattered MacRuby notes I found out how to do this.  Of course it's one of my early attempted solutions; **the trick was installing the (MacRuby) *BridgeSupport Preview*** which is separate from the MacRuby install and was something I hadn't known about nor needed until now.  Getting that put down here will hopefully save someone the aggravation of searching for an answer that isn't obviously connected to the problem.  Here's a "complete" listing of my original example (above) with the missing piece added:

```
CATransaction.begin  # start the transaction
#
# ...set up animation (works fine!)
#
CATransaction.setCompletionBlock( Proc.new { puts "I'm done!" })      <-------
CATransaction.commit  # end the transaction
```

where the 'puts' statement can be replaced with desired code to be carried out on the completion of the animation.

The more general answer for **specifying a *block*** to a Cocoa method is to use:

***`Proc.new { ...code block... }`***

in the method invocation (as above).  Arguments can also be supplied, if they are specified in the method documentation, by using the normal ruby block definition syntax.

The ***MacRuby BridgeSupport Preview can be downloaded from [here](http://www.macruby.org/files/)*** (as can the MacRuby current and nightly releases).